# Unit testing mongoose validation with promise resolve/reject

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I'm struggling to find a way to unit test the validation of a field in  mongoose. I currently have the following test:

```
it('should be invalid if googleId is empty', () => 
  testBook.googleId = '';
  const newBook = new Book(testBook);
  return newBook.validate().catch((err) => {
    should.exist(err.errors.googleId);
  });
});
```

This test is not working as intended because, if I have a correct validation for `googleId`, the test will pass because it will assert the `err.errors.googleId` exists, but if I don't have any validation for `googleId`, it will also pass because the `.catch()` never gets called and it assumes the test is passing.

I've tried putting `should.fail()` inside a `.then()`, but that way it always ends up in `.catch()` but with different errors, if there's no validation it will be catched with the `should.fail()` error, if there's validation it will catch with the model validation error.

What would be the best way to achieve this kind of testing?

Thanks alot!

EDIT:
I've tried using the callback of `newBook.validate()` and it works, but I never use callbacks for model methods, I always tend to use promises, so should I be using the callback in this particular case or there's still a better way to handle it using promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second parameter to then and put something that throws in the first for example:

```
return newBook.validate().then(
    resp => throw new Error("Test failed this should not resolve"),
    err =>  should.exist(err.errors.googleId);
});
```

So now if the `newBook.validate()` is not rejected the test will fail. Since you aren't using `catch()` you don't stop it from causing the test to fail like it should. If the promise is rejected like it should be your test passes (assuming it meets the conditions set). This works because unlike `catch()` the error callback of `then()` doesn't catch errors thrown in `then()`. Of course you can put anything in the first callback that throws an error like `assert.fail()` or whatever your library has.

Comment: Oh that was great, I didn't know about the `then()` second callback, I'm now returning should.fail() in the first callback and making the assertion in the second as you said and all works great :D Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`chai-as-promised`](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) plugin that includes helpers to make Promise testing work more like normal chai expect/should does.

`.rejectedWith` and `.rejected` handle errors largely like regular `.throw`.

```
const chai = require('chai')
chai.should()
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'))

it('should be invalid if googleId is empty', function(){
  testBook.googleId = ''
  const newBook = new Book(testBook)
  return newBook.validate()
     .should.be.rejectedWith('Validation Failed')
     .and.eventually.have.nested.property('errors.googleId')
});
```

Just make sure you load the plugin last if you are loading any other [chai plugins](http://chaijs.com/plugins/) otherwise things go haywire.